# error in reading a wav file with C++

Tags: c++, audio, wav, riff

I have a .wav file and I want to read it in C++. I have done some research on the RIFF file header and wrote a code to load it.

```
#include <iostream>
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <string.h>
#include <math.h>

using namespace std;
#define BUFFER_LEN 4096

int main(int argc,char * argv[])
{
    // Buffers etc..
    char ChunkID[4], Format[4], Subchunk1ID[4],Subchunk2ID[4];
    int ChunkSize,Subchunk1Size, SampleRate, ByteRate,Subchunk2Size;
    short AudioFormat, NumChannels, BlockAlign, BitsPerSample;

    // Read the wave file
    FILE *fhandle=fopen(argv[1],"rb");
    fread(ChunkID,1,4,fhandle);
    fread(&ChunkSize,4,1,fhandle);
    fread(Format,1,4,fhandle);
    fread(Subchunk1ID,1,4,fhandle);
    fread(&Subchunk1Size,4,1,fhandle);
    fread(&AudioFormat,2,1,fhandle);
    fread(&NumChannels,2,1,fhandle);
    fread(&SampleRate,4,1,fhandle);
    fread(&ByteRate,4,1,fhandle);
    fread(&BlockAlign,2,1,fhandle);
    fread(&BitsPerSample,2,1,fhandle);
    fread(&Subchunk2ID,1,4,fhandle);
    fread(&Subchunk2Size,4,1,fhandle);
    fclose(fhandle);

    // print RIFF info
    printf("\%c",ChunkID[0]);
    printf("\%c",ChunkID[1]);
    printf("\%c",ChunkID[2]);
    printf("\%c",ChunkID[3]);
    cout << endl;

    // print chunk size
    printf("%d",ChunkSize);
    cout << endl;

    // print format
    printf("\%c",Format[0]);
    printf("\%c",Format[1]);
    printf("\%c",Format[2]);
    printf("\%c",Format[3]);
    cout << endl;

    // print sub chunk 1 ID
    printf("\%c",Subchunk1ID[0]);
    printf("\%c",Subchunk1ID[1]);
    printf("\%c",Subchunk1ID[2]);
    printf("\%c",Subchunk1ID[3]);
    cout << endl;

    // print sub chunk 1 size
    printf("%d",Subchunk1Size);
    cout << endl;

    // print audio format
    printf("%hd",AudioFormat);
    cout << endl;

    // print number of channels
    printf("%hd",NumChannels);
    cout << endl;    

    return 0;
}
```

However, it is very wired that I run this code on my input file OS.wav. It output the information:

```
RIFF
307201488
WAVE
Fake
2
0
28006
```

You can see the "fmt" is "Fake".

Then I use sox to convert this wav file by:

```
sox OS.wav test.wav
```

and run my code again. It has the information:

```
RIFF
307200050
WAVE
fmt 
18
3
2
```

I did not change any thing. But the header information is so different. Could anyone tell me why this happen, please?

Thank you.

Comment: Could the original WAV file have been exported from a cracked program? It could be a demo limitation that was crudely imposed by the programmer...

Comment: Or, it could simply be a custom `Fake` chunk that is not being skipped before reaching the real `fmt` chunk.  RIFF/WAVE chunks can be in any order, as long as the `fmt` chunk is before the `data` chunk. Running the file through sox is most likely stripping off the `Fake` chunk.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You are assuming the `fmt` chunk is the first sub-chunk within the `RIFF/WAVE` chunk.  That is not a requirement or a guarantee.  Do some more research on the RIFF/WAV format. `WAVE` sub-chunks can appear in any order, the only rule being that the `fmt` chunk must appear before the `data` chunk, but other chunks can appear before, after, and in between them.

The correct way to parse your file is to loop through the sub-chunks one at a time.  Read a chunkID and chunkSize, then read the specified number of bytes (taking padding into account) and process them according to the chunkID as needed, and then repeat until EOF.  This lets you process the chunks you are interested in and skip the ones you don't care about.  Don't make any assumptions about their order (but do validate the one special case), and definitely don't assume the `fmt` chunk is the first chunk, because it might not be.

Try something more like this:

```
#include <iostream>
#include <istream>
#include <stdexcept>
#include <string>

using namespace std;

struct chunkHdr
{
   char id[4];
   unsigned int size;
   unsigned int pos;
};

bool isChunkID(const chunkHdr &c, char id1, char id2, char id3, char id4)
{
    return ((c.id[0] == id1) &&
            (c.id[1] == id2) &&
            (c.id[2] == id3) &&
            (c.id[3] == id4));
}

void read(ifstream &f, void *buffer, streamsize size, chunkHdr *parent)
{
    if (!f.read(static_cast<char*>(buffer), size))
    {
        if (f.eof())
            throw runtime_error("Unexpected EOF while reading from file");
        throw runtime_error("Unable to read from file");
    }
    if (parent) parent->pos += size;
}

void skip(ifstream &f, streamsize size, chunkHdr *parent)
{
    if (!f.seekg(size, ios_base::cur))
        throw runtime_error("Unable to read from file");
    if (parent) parent->pos += size;
}

void read(ifstream &f, chunkHdr &c, chunkHdr *parent)
{
    read(f, c.id, 4, parent);
    read(f, &(c.size), 4, parent);
    c.pos = 0;
}

int main(int argc, char * argv[])
{
    // Buffers etc..
    chunk riff, wave, chk;
    bool fmtFound = false;

    try
    {
        // Open the wave file
        ifstream wavFile(argv[1], ios_base::binary);
        if (!wavFile)
            throw runtime_error("Unable to open file");

        // check the RIFF header
        read(wavFile, riff, NULL);
        if (!isChunkID(riff, 'R', 'I', 'F', 'F'))
            throw runtime_error("File is not a RIFF file");
        cout << "RIFF Size: " << riff.size << endl;

        // check the WAVE header
        read(wavFile, wave.id, 4, &riff);
        wave.size = riff.size - 4;
        wave.pos = 0;

        cout << "RIFF Type: '" << string(wave.id, 4) << "'" << endl;
        if (!isChunkID(wave, 'W', 'A', 'V', 'E'))
            throw runtime_error("File is not a WAV file");

        // read WAVE chunks
        while (wave.pos < wave.size)
        {
            read(wavFile, chk, &wave);
            cout << "Chunk: '" << string(chk.id, 4) << "', Size: " << chk.size << endl;

            if (isChunkID(chk, 'f', 'm', 't', ' '))
            {
                if (fmtFound)
                    throw runtime_error("More than one FMT chunk encountered");
                fmtFound = true;

                unsigned int SampleRate, ByteRate;
                unsigned short AudioFormat, NumChannels, BlockAlign, BitsPerSample, ExtraSize;

                read(wavFile, &AudioFormat, 2, &chk);
                read(wavFile, &NumChannels, 2, &chk);
                read(wavFile, &SampleRate, 4, &chk);
                read(wavFile, &ByteRate, 4, &chk);
                read(wavFile, &BlockAlign, 2, &chk);

                cout << "  Audio Format: " << AudioFormat << endl;
                cout << "  Channels: " << NumChannels << endl;
                cout << "  Sample Rate: " << SampleRate << endl;
                cout << "  Byte Rate: " << ByteRate << endl;
                cout << "  BlockAlign: " << BlockAlign << endl;

                if (chk.size >= 16)
                {
                    read(wavFile, &BitsPerSample, 2, &chk);
                    cout << "  Bits per Sample: " << BitsPerSample << endl;
                }

                if (chk.size >= 18)
                {
                    read(wavFile, &ExtraSize, 2, &chk);
                    cout << "  Extra Size: " << ExtraSize << endl;

                    if (ExtraSize > 0)
                    {
                        // read and process ExtraSize number of bytes as needed...
                        skip(wavFile, ExtraSize, &chk);
                    }
                }

                if (chk.pos < chk.size)
                    skip(wavFile, chk.size - chk.pos, &chk);
            }
            else if (isChunkID(chk, 'd', 'a', 't', 'a'))
            {
                if (!fmtFound)
                    throw runtime_error("No FMT chunk encountered before DATA chunk");

                // read and process chk.size number of bytes as needed...
                skip(wavFile, chk.size, &chk);
            }

            // read other chunks as needed...

            else
            {
                // skip an unwanted chunk
                skip(wavFile, chk.size, &chk);
            }

            // all done with this chunk
            wave.pos += chk.pos;

            // check for chunk padding
            if (chk.size % 2)
                skip(wavFile, 1, &wave);
        }
    }
    catch (const exception &e)
    {
        cout << "Error! " << e.what() << endl;
    }

    return 0;
}
```

Comment: Thank you. I got the format online. It seems to me that the format is fixed. Do you have any recommendation on what I can learn the wave files processing or say audio processing?

Comment: The format is *NOT* fixed, and your test WAV file proves that. The WAV format has many chunk types defined (not all of which are used in all WAV files), and custom chunk types can be used as well without affecting audio processing, since the `fmt` and `data` chunks are processed independently of other chunks.